# discord bot : undefined name channel

Tags: python, discord

```
import os
import discord

import random
from prettytable import PrettyTable
from PIL import Image


client = discord.client()

    
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(client))
  

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return


    if message.content.startswith("$picture"):
       
        await channel.send(file=discord.File("images.jpg"))
    


client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Hello this is my first time using stack overflow I apologize ahead of time if my post has some mistakes,
so I was trying to have my discord upload a picture when entering a "$picture" in the chat box, but I get an red underline at the line that says `await channel.send(file=discord.File("images.jpg"))` Saying "undefined named 'channel'" I tried looking into it but couldnt find much. Any ideas? thank you.

Comment: This means your variable isn't defined anywhere. @GGberry has the correct solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do `message.channel.send()` and not `channel.send()`.

So instead of

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return


    if message.content.startswith("$picture"):
       
        await channel.send(file=discord.File("images.jpg"))
```

You can do

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return


    if message.content.startswith("$picture"):
       
        await message.channel.send(file=discord.File("images.jpg"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! Just a tip: people usually accept the answer that solves your problem so that no additional people looks at this question in the goal of solving it.